# Not able to create Outlook item in server code

Tags: c#, botframework, com-interop

I am trying to send meeting invites from user to a contact person using my chatbot. My solution is working fine when I run outlook in the background but when I close it, it throws an exception:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

When I tried to deploy this code on my server it showed me the same exception.
The code works on my local machine when I keep outlook running in the background.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
// outlookApplication.Startup += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_StartupEventHandler(outlookApp_Startup);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApplication.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);


appointmentItem.Subject = "Dina need further assistance";
appointmentItem.Body = "Please Help me ";
appointmentItem.Location = "Room #1";
appointmentItem.Start = DateTime.Now;
foreach (string email in Recipients)
{
    appointmentItem.Recipients.Add(email);
}

//appointmentItem.Recipients.Add("karmit.dhawan@accenture.com");

appointmentItem.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
appointmentItem.ReminderSet = true;
appointmentItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;
appointmentItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
appointmentItem.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
appointmentItem.MeetingStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;

appointmentItem.Recipients.ResolveAll();
appointmentItem.Display(true);
```

Comment: That is a very generic exception message. Do you have a stack trace or something to help narrow this down?

Comment: If you are targeting Office365 or event Exchange OnPremises on recent releases, I highly suggest that you use Microsoft Graph instead of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x80080005
  Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
  Source=mscorlib

Comment: Is this the cause? [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)